# Play audio smoothly after selected from listview

Tags: android

```
public void playSong(int i) {
        // Play song
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(LocalModel.getInstance()
                    .getSongsListArrayList().get(i).getSong());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

            // Displaying Song title
            // String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            // songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            audioSeekbar.setProgress(0);
            audioSeekbar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar        
            updateProgressBar();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Playing song from remote server, but while calling this method on create method getting stuck or slow to play on next activity.what i am expecting when user select any song then audio player activity should open smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Detect which line is consuming time to execute and then call it on separate thread.